# How to separate array objects?

Tags: modifiers

I made 5 array objects, apply array modifier and then got 1 object.

How to separate this 1 object into 5 individual pieces in one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the editmode, select all vertices and press P: By Loose Parts
Blender splits all unconnected vertices into an object

Comment: Does not change anything for me.